# Eclipse Java code style formatter

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, eclipse-formatter

How to configure the Eclipse Java code style formatter to start the code following a brace on the same line as the brace?

```
class Example
{   Example()
    {
    }
    void bar(int p)
    {   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {    //a comment
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:  Please read the question carefully.  I am not asking a general question on how to use the formatter.  It is **easy** to get the formatter to do this:

```
class Example
{
    //Code starts on the line following the brace
    Example()
    {
    }
}
```

It is **NOT easy** to get it to do this:

```
class Example
{   Example() //Code starts on the same line as the brace
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly this is one of those things you can Google and get over 500 different solutions. Like [HERE](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcodestyle%2Fref-preferences-formatter.htm) for example.

Comment: Did you read the question?  Specifically "start the code following a brace **on the same line** as the brace"

Comment: Is it me or are the two examples completely identical?

Comment: Its just you.  Example() is on a new line in the first instance, and on the same line as the opening brace in the second instance.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain his downvote or did he misinterpret the question because it wasn't read carefully?

Comment: No there was no misinterpretation. I simple downvoted this question because there are already an infinite amount of answers to it.

Comment: The link you posted [HERE](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcodestyle%2Fref-preferences-formatter.htm) shows general information on how to use the formatter.  It doesn't show how to get code **ON THE SAME LINE AS THE BRACE**  Your post clearly indicates that you didn't read the question carefully.  If there are an infinite number of answers then please post one that shows code **ON THE SAME LINE AS THE BRACE** and I'll accept it.  I know RTFM is common advice, how about RTFQ(uestion)?

Comment: @Tdorno If you had a shred of integrity you would admit your mistake in downvoting the question.

Comment: @monzie shots fired haha...

Comment: @Tdorno Whatever, you and I know what type of person you are.

Comment: @monzie Gonna have to say no you don't.

Comment: @Tdorno A man admits his mistakes, a coward hides from them.  I notice you haven't posted an answer despite the supposed infinite number that exist, nor have you supported your downvote with a single fact.

Comment: @monzie You got it all figured out don't you?

Comment: @Tdorno No, but I find it easy to recognize a gutless wimp

Comment: @monzie Man now I don't have a gut?

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project and go to properties.
Then select Java Code Style > Formatter. Click New to create new formatter